# navigator.clipboard.readText() not work on android devices

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, clipboard

I have this function that manipulates copied text but it doesn't work on android... on normal browsers it works, but my site is also turned into an app for android devices and on devices it doesn't work...

```
 navigator.clipboard
    .readText()
    .then((clipboardText) => {
      const listCopiedToArray = clipboardText
        .split('\n')
        .filter((el) => el !== '')
        .map((todo) => todo.replace(/\b-\b/g, '').trim());

      if (listCopiedToArray.includes('ListCopied')) {
        // I do my own thing
      } else {
        // I do other things
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

How can I solve it? I remember that I also had problems with: `navigator.clipboard.writeText(arrayNoCommas); //it didn't work on android`
and I solved it with:

```
  document.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', mytext);
    e.preventDefault();
  }); // This works on android
```

Comment: are you using your ip to run it on android??, it wont work then . window.isSecureContext must be true in order to use clipboard which is only true for "localhost" & https sites/ domains, its false for http / ip

Comment: no it's a site created with vue and turned into an android app with kodular... so there's no way to solve it?